# Connect Rails with React Native

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, react-native

For a university project I had to build a website in Ruby on Rails and deployed it via Azure. The website is live and running smoothly.

After two weeks the website has been deployed, my professor asked me to create a React Native app using the Rails Backed.

So far, I have created the front-end using React Native BUT I have no clue how to connect it to the Rails backend (I guess I need an API but not sure how to do it).

I googled it around, but there is not a specific tutorial that helps me in connecting a Rails live website with React Native.
I am new to this world and need some guidance in the right direction.

Comment: i used both, rails as back and ract-native mobile, just tie them through api

Comment: Thanks! Can you suggest me a specific API builder or a tutorial I can use?

Comment: with jbuilder is simple, by adding to routes .json ending

Comment: Does my Rails website has to be live in order to test the jbuilder on the app, right?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new rails application that functions as the api. You'll have to run the rails new command with an additional `--api` flag.

```
rails new rails-api-with-react --api
```

2. Move into the directory

```
rails-api-with-react
```

3. Start your server

```
rails server
```

4. Use a tool like [Postman][1] to check that the server is running.
5. After you confirm that the server is up and running, make a get request in your **React** application to the **Rails** server

Comment: Thanks! I do not get how the original Rails and the App will communica. I mean: if I create a new Rails application as API with --api, how does this new application know that has to connect to the original Rails?